# How to display nested array in codeigniter (country - state - city hierarchy)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to display the nested array of the list I have of country, state and city:

In the first array I need the `country id`, `country name` and `state id` (state id is in another array)

The Second is `state id`, `state name`, `city id` (city id is another array)

What SQL query will go with this?
Can anybody help?

Comment: please show the respective output you prefer

Comment: what you tried till now?

Comment: @NarendraSisodia I want to display array like this:

Array[3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will explain with the help of an example **(since you haven't provided any content from yourside)**

**Database:** (3 tables)

```
1) `world_countries`

id  |   name
 1  |   Algeria
 2  |   Albania
80  |   India
266 |   United States of America
280 |   Zimbabwe 
_______________________________________________

2) `world_states`

id  |   name            | country_id
 1  |   Andhra Pradesh  |     80
 2  |   Assam           |     80
28  |   Uttarkhand      |     80
29  |   Uttarpradesh    |     80
150 |   California      |     266 
170 |   New York        |     266

_______________________________________________

3) `world_cities`

id  |   name            |  state_id
28  |   California      |     150
61  |   Guwahati        |     2
85  |   Hyderabad       |     1
122 |   New York        |     170
```

**Model:** (models/world_model.php)

```
<?php
class World_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);
    }

    public function get_all_countries()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('world_countries');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_countries($where)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('world_countries', $where);
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_all_states()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('world_states');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_states($where)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('world_states', $where);
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_all_cites()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('world_cities');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_cities($where)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('world_cities', $where);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

**Controller:** (controllers/xyz.php)

```
<?php
class Xyz extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('world_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $countries = $this->world_model->get_all_countries();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($countries as $c)
        {
            $data['c_s'][$i]['country_id'] = $c['id'];
            $data['c_s'][$i]['country_name'] = $c['name'];

            $states = $this->world_model->get_states(array('country_id' => $c['id']));
            foreach($states as $s)
                $data['c_s'][$i]['state_id'][] = $s['id'];

            $i++;
        }

        $states = $this->world_model->get_all_states();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($states as $s)
        {
            $data['s_c'][$i]['state_id'] = $s['id'];
            $data['s_c'][$i]['state_name'] = $s['name'];

            $cities = $this->world_model->get_states(array('state_id' => $s['id']));
            foreach($cities as $c)
                $data['s_c'][$i]['city_id'][] = $c['id'];

            $i++;
        }

        $this->load->view('xyz', $data);
    }
}
```

**View:** (views/xyz.php)

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>Country ID</td>
       <td>Country Name</td>
       <td>State ID</td>
   </tr>

   <?php foreach($c_s as $p1) { foreach($p1['state_id'] as $p2) { ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $p1['country_id']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p1['country_name']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p2['state_id']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php } } ?>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
       <td>State ID</td>
       <td>State Name</td>
       <td>City ID</td>
   </tr>

   <?php foreach($s_c as $p1) { foreach($p1['city_id'] as $p2) { ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $p1['state_id']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p1['state_name']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $p2['city_id']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php } } ?>    
</table>
```

Comment: Note that `$query->result()` will return an array of objects so you'll need `$query->result_array()` instead

Comment: @Gervs: Good catch !! For simplicity, I'll make everything `array` in that case. Thank you :)

Comment: @parag Tyagi i tried your code but facing error of "Use of undefined constant c_s - assumed 'c_s'....i am a newbie to codeigniter please guide where i am wrong

Comment: @Anonymus: My bad. I haven't added quotes (it should be like `'c_s'` and not `c_s`). Kindly check updated ans.

Comment: @ParagTyagi thank you that sorted out, now i am getting this error: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Can you tell me its coming on which line.

Comment: $data['c_s'][$i]['country_id'] = $c['id'];   
$data['c_s'][$i]['country_name'] = $c['name'];
$states = $this->world_model->get_states(array('country_id' => $c['id']));

On These three lines i am having this Notice

Comment: Are you using the updated answer. Because we are no more using objects now. This error comes when we are trying to get value of object which doesn't exist. Like using something like `$c->name` and column `name` doesn't exist in the table. Try debugging yourself. Use `print_r()` or such to debug and make way.

Comment: @ParagTyagi Thanks that sorted out!